# Ionic3 lazy loading a Component in Page

Tags: lazy-loading, ionic3

I am working to an app that will be like a ppt presentation with a homepage, then slides(which are lazyloaded), each slide will have a navigation bar with: prev, home and next btn. 
SO I thought: if that navigation will be common for all slides why not have it like a separate component, with a `navCtrl` and `nextSLide` will be transmitted like an `@Input()`, `goHome`- will be a `seRoot()` and back will be `navCtrl.pop()` - `navPop` directly in html. I will post code below :

**slide1.ts**

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-slide1',
  templateUrl: 'slide1.html',
})
export class Slide1Page {
  link:string = "Slide2Page"
}
```

**slide1.htm**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <app-nav [toSlide]="link"></app-nav>
</ion-content>
```

**nav.ts**

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: 'nav.html'
})
export class NavComponent {
  @Input() toSlide;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
}
```

**nav.html**

```
<button class="nav_left" navPop></button>
<button class="to_home" (click)="goHome()"></button>
<button class="nav_right" [navPush]="toSlide"></button>
```

**nav.module.ts** I've made it `IonicPagemodule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavComponent } from './nav';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(NavComponent),
  ],
  exports: [
    NavComponent
  ]
})
export class NavComponentModule {}
```

When I navigate from homePage to slide1Page I got a long error(chunk of it here):

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'toSlide' since it isn't a known property of 'app-nav'. 1. If 'app-nav' is an Angular component and it has 'toSlide' input, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'app-nav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

I want to know if my approach is good or doable, cuz I don't wanna spend time for nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there error was because I didn't include `NavCOmponent` in `slide1.module.ts`

```
import { NavComponent } from './../../components/nav/nav';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Slide1Page } from './slide1';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Slide1Page,
    NavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(Slide1Page),
  ],
  exports: [
    Slide1Page,
    NavComponent
  ]
})
export class Slide1PageModule {}
```

Still - is this a good approach?